# Dual booting ubuntu with Windows screwed up Windows boot animation

Tags: grub2, windows-10, bootloader

Just dual booted my laptop with Ubuntu. But whenever I boot into Windows 10 using Ubuntu GRUB, whole screen turns pinkish (Windows logo disappears but spinning dot remains) and then leaves me at my Login window. How can I bring Windows logo back?

Comment: Please link to the instructions that you carefully followed to install your dual-boot system.

Comment: i though there's no way for fixing that,just get used to... it's the sacrifice of using linux

Comment: Ubuntu files/programs don't mess with Windows (unless the user do something wrong).

Comment: There is no Windows logo where you think it is, just black screen. What happens when you boot from Grub is that Grub gives you a nicer background as courtesy while Windows is (slowly) loading, instead of just a black screen with the spinning dots. And, if you ask me, that's a ridiculous concern, not a serious question.

Comment: I think that GRUB reinitializes the system framebuffer or something, and the Windows bootloader doesn't update it.